# Clarification needed about Python CSV file format parsing

Tags: python, parsing, csv

Format is like:

```
CHINA;2002-06-25 00:00:00.000;5,60
CHINA;2002-06-26 00:00:00.000;5,32
CHINA;2002-06-27 00:00:00.000;5,31
```

and I try to use Python's CSV tools to parse it but cannot understand the paragraph, [source](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

And while the module doesn’t directly support parsing strings, it can easily be done:

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(['one,two,three']):
    print row
```

Could someone clarify the line `['one,two,three']`? How would you use it with format `A;B;C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs you quote are talking about the difference between parsing csv data stored in a file, and csv data stored in a string.  It doesn't have to do with the format of the data.

You should be able to read your data with something like:

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')
for row in csv_reader:
    # do something with row....
```